# JSF Backing Bean method not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, method-call, backing-beans

When i click the command button which triggers the editUser(User) method or the one that triggers the editClient(User) method in my backing bean, the methods ain't called anymore. It worked before, but now just nothing is called. The page is reloaded.

What could be wrong here ???

Here is my view:

```
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="#{userManagement.activeOverviewTab}" id="overview" rendered="#{loginControl.isAllowedForClientUserCreation()}">
<p:tab title="#{text.tabClients}" rendered="#{loginControl.isAllowedForUserManagement()}">
    <h:form id="clientForm">
    <p:dataTable value="#{userManagement.clientUsers}" var="clientUser" paginator="true" rows="5" id="clientTable">
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colClientName}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{clientUser.client.clientName}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colClientEmail}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{clientUser.client.email}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colClientJobLayout}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{clientUser.client.reportLayout}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersLogin}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{clientUser.login}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersPassword}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{clientUser.password}"/></p:column>            
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersAction}"/></f:facet>
            <p:commandLink onclick="clientDlg.show()">
                <h:graphicImage name="icons/pencil.png" title="#{text.editClientUser}" />
            </p:commandLink>
                <p:dialog header="#{text.editClientUser}" widgetVar="clientDlg" modal="true" resizable="false" width="350" height="190" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="explode">
                <h:form id="customerEditForm">
                <p:growl id="clientUserMessages"/>
                <br/>
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnsClasses="odd, even">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colClientName}"/><h:inputText value="#{clientUser.client.clientName}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colClientEmail}"/><h:inputText value="#{clientUser.client.email}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colClientJobLayout}"/><h:inputText value="#{clientUser.client.reportLayout}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colUsersLogin}"/><h:inputText value="#{clientUser.login}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colUsersPassword}"/><h:inputText value="#{clientUser.password}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <br/>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{text.applyButton}" type="button" action="#{userManagement.editClient(clientUser)}" onclick="clientDlg.hide()"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{text.abortButton}" type="button" onclick="clientDlg.hide()" />                    
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>

        </p:column>             
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:tab>

<p:tab title="#{text.tabPrinter}" rendered="#{loginControl.isAllowedForClientUserCreation()}">
    <h:form id="userForm">
    <p:dataTable value="#{userManagement.printUsers}" var="printUser" paginator="true" rows="5" id="userTable">
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersUsername}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{printUser.name}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersLogin}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{printUser.login}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersPassword}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{printUser.password}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colsUsersAssignedClient}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{printUser.client.clientName}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersLocked}"/></f:facet><h:graphicImage name="icons/lock.png" rendered="#{printUser.locked == 1}"/></p:column>
        <p:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{text.colUsersAction}"/></f:facet>
            <p:commandLink onclick="dlg.show()">
                <h:graphicImage name="icons/pencil.png" title="Drucker bearbeiten" />
            </p:commandLink>
                <p:dialog header="#{text.editPrintUser}" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" resizable="false" width="350" height="190" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="explode">
                <h:form id="printerEditForm">
                <p:growl showDetail="true" id="printerMessages" />  
                <br />
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="odd, even">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colUsersLogin}"/><h:inputText value="#{printUser.login}" />    
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colUsersPassword}"/><h:inputText value="#{printUser.password}" />  
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colsUsersAssignedClient}"/>
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{printUser.client}" converter="de.flexicon.webtools.entity.Client">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{userManagement.clients}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>                          
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colUsersLocked}"/><h:inputText value="#{printUser.locked}" />  
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{text.colClientEmail}"/><h:inputText value="#{printUser.email}" />   
                    </p:panelGrid>  
                    <br />
                        <p:commandButton value="#{text.applyButton}" type="button" action="#{userManagement.editUser(printUser)}" onclick="dlg.hide()"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{text.abortButton}" type="button" onclick="dlg.hide()" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:dialog>

        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

And here is my backing bean:

```
package de.flexicon.webtools.util;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;    
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import de.flexicon.webtools.entity.Client;
import de.flexicon.webtools.entity.User;
import de.flexicon.webtools.entity.dao.ClientDAO;
import de.flexicon.webtools.entity.dao.RoleDAO;
import de.flexicon.webtools.entity.dao.UserDAO;
import de.flexicon.webtools.entity.report.constants.UserRole;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean(name="userManagement")
@ViewScoped
public class UserManagement implements Serializable
{

private User newUser;
private Client selectedClient;

private List<User> clientUsers;
private List<User> printUsers;

private List<Client> clients;

private int activeOverviewTab = -1;

public UserManagement(){

}

public User getNewUser() {
    if(newUser==null){
        newUser = new User();
    }
    return newUser;
}

public void setNewUser(User newUser) {
    this.newUser = newUser;
}



/**
 * Legt einen neuen Drucker mit Kundenzuordnung an!
 */
    public void createNewTechUser(ActionEvent e){

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ctx.getApplication().getResourceBundle(ctx, "text");

    try
    {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
        user.setLocked(0);
        user.setLogin(newUser.getLogin());
        user.setName(newUser.getName());
        user.setPassword(newUser.getPassword());
        userDAO.persist(user);

        RoleDAO roleDAO = new RoleDAO();
        user.getRoles().add(roleDAO.findById(UserRole.DRUCKER));

        user.setClient(selectedClient);
        userDAO.update(user);


        ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, bundle.getString("msgNewTechUserCreated"), bundle.getString("msgNewTechUserCreated")));
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Logger.getRootLogger().error(bundle.getString("logErrorCreatingUser") + ex);
        ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, bundle.getString("logErrorCreatingUser") + ": " + ex.getMessage(), bundle.getString("logErrorCreatingUser") + ": " + ex.getMessage()));
    }
    finally{
        setActiveOverviewTab(1);
    }
}

public void createNewClient(ActionEvent e)
{
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ctx.getApplication().getResourceBundle(ctx, "text");
    try
    {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
        user.setLocked(0);
        user.setLogin(newUser.getLogin());
        user.setName(newUser.getName());
        user.setPassword(newUser.getPassword());
        userDAO.persist(user);

        RoleDAO roleDAO = new RoleDAO();
        user.getRoles().add(roleDAO.findById(UserRole.KUNDE));

        ClientDAO clientDAO = new ClientDAO();
        Client client = new Client();
         client.setClientName(user.getName());
         client.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        clientDAO.persist(client);

        user.setClient(client);
        userDAO.update(user);


        ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, bundle.getString("msgNewTechUserCreated"), bundle.getString("msgNewTechUserCreated")));
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Logger.getRootLogger().error(bundle.getString("logErrorCreatingUser") + ex);
        ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, bundle.getString("logErrorCreatingUser") + ": " + ex.getMessage(), bundle.getString("logErrorCreatingUser") + ": " + ex.getMessage()));
    }
    finally{
        setActiveOverviewTab(0);
    }
}


public Client getSelectedClient() {
    return selectedClient;
}

public void setSelectedClient(Client selectedClient) {
    this.selectedClient = selectedClient;
}


public List<User> getClientUsers() {
    if(clientUsers==null){

        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        clientUsers= userDAO.getUsersByRole(UserRole.KUNDE);
    }
    return clientUsers;
}

public void setClientUsers(List<User> clientsUsers) {
    this.clientUsers = clientsUsers;
}

public void setPrintUsers(List<User> printUsers) {
    this.printUsers = printUsers;
}

public List<User> getPrintUsers() {
    if(printUsers==null){
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        printUsers = userDAO.getUsersByRole(UserRole.DRUCKER);
    }
    return printUsers;
}

public List<Client> getClients() {
    if(clients==null){
        ClientDAO clientDAO = new ClientDAO();
        setClients(clientDAO.getClientsOrderedByName());
    }
    return clients;
}

public void setClients(List<Client> clients) {
    this.clients = clients;
}

public void editUser(User user){
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    userDAO.update(user);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResourceBundle bundle = context.getApplication().getResourceBundle(context, "text");
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, bundle.getString("printerUpdated"), bundle.getString("descUpdatedPrintUser")));
    setActiveOverviewTab(1);
}

public void editClient(User user){
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    userDAO.update(user);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResourceBundle bundle = context.getApplication().getResourceBundle(context, "text");
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, bundle.getString("printerUpdated"), bundle.getString("descUpdatedPrintUser")));
    setActiveOverviewTab(0);
}

public void setActiveOverviewTab(int tabIdx){
    this.activeOverviewTab = tabIdx;
}

public int getActiveOverviewTab(){
    return this.activeOverviewTab;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You are nesting forms.
See [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked) for more details.